# Excel office-js API - Get ranges of specific sheets

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

The Excel document's sheets are the days of the week (Sunday-Friday) - which need to be iterated over.
My question is: How?

My code attempts (which all resulted as a failure):

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    const currentSheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    const worksheetDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
        sheetRanges[worksheetDays[i]] = currentSheets.load("values");
    }
    return context.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(sheetRanges.Sunday.values); // null
    });
});
```

Next attempt:

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    const worksheetDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
    const sheetRanges = {};
    const currentSheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
         sheetRanges[worksheetDays[i]] = currentSheets.getItem(worksheetDays[i]).load("values");
    }
    return context.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(sheetRanges.Sunday.values); // null
    });
});
```

Next:

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    const worksheetDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
    const sheetRanges = {};
    const currentSheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
         sheetRanges[worksheetDays[i]] = currentSheets.getItem(worksheetDays[i]).getRange().load("values");
    }
    return context.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(sheetRanges.Sunday.values); // null
    });
});
```

Next:

```
Excel.run(function(context) {
    const worksheetDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
    var sheetRanges = {};
    const currentSheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
        sheetRanges[worksheetDays[i]] = currentSheets.load("name");
    }
})
.then(context.sync)
.then(function () {
     for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
        sheetRanges[worksheetDays] = sheetRanges[worksheetDays].load("values");
    }
 })
.then(function () {
    console.log(sheetRanges.Sunday.values); // null
});
```

Basically, I'm lost. I just need to get the cell values of all sheets.
How to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very very close.  In fact, your third attempt was almost correct.  But for the sake of others who might come across this question, let me describe the issue with the first two code blocks, first.

For the first two attempts, the problem is that you can only load properties *that actually exist on the object*.  And unfortunately for your code, `values` isn't a property on a `worksheet` object.

Personally, I find that the easiest way is to write the code as if the properties are already loaded (and using IntelliSense to guide you).  Then, go up one or more lines, and do the `load` statement, just as you did, specifying the property name that you're using (i.e., `range.load('value')`), and make sure that you have a `context.sync()`, properly chained (which you correctly do) or `await`-ed (if you're using TypeScript).

Now, the issue with your almost-correct approach #3 is that if you are constructing a `Range` for the *entire* worksheet and then loaded its `values` property, `values` would be `null`, because such range is unbounded (a million+ rows by 16k columns; there is no way you want to shuttle that sort of data between the host Excel application and JavaScript).  So the API you want to use is `sheet.getUsedRange()`.

So, with all of this being said, you can take your 3rd code attempt and just replace

```
currentSheets.getItem(worksheetDays[i]).getRange().load("values");
```

with

```
currentSheets.getItem(worksheetDays[i]).getUsedRange().load("values");
```

So you were literally 4 characters away from having it right on your third try.  By the way, if you had been loading the `address` property, you would in fact have gotten it right.  At that point, the issue wasn't the way you were loading values, but rather the fact that unbounded ranges (and also inconsistent values, for things like bold/italic/color/etc if they are different across multiple cells) return a `null`.  I'll pass feedback to our content team to make sure this is made clearer.

So, final code (and also TypeScript-ifying it for good measure :-), so you can have good IntelliSense):

```
await Excel.run(async context => {
    const worksheetDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", /*...*/];
    const sheetRanges = {} as { [key: string]: Excel.Range }

    const currentSheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    for (let i = 0; i < worksheetDays.length; i++) {
        sheetRanges[worksheetDays[i]] = currentSheets.getItem(worksheetDays[i]).getUsedRange().load("values");
    }

    await context.sync();
    console.log(sheetRanges["Sunday"].values);
});
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/a045beb300c9b1a86276f6ff99fd64a4.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).

Finally, I would be remiss not to mention that for many of the above topics -- i.e., how to properly load properties, understanding how collection access works, using TypeScript inside of an Office Add-in, and more -- you might find the book "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins)" a valuable resource.  For full disclosure: I am the author of said book.  But I can also guarantee you'd find it useful.  And for that matter, the LeanPub store itself offers a 45-day unconditional 100% "happiness guarantee" for the book (which I've never had anyone request a refund for).

All the best, and good luck in your add-in development experience!  Do keep posting questions if you run into issues...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was hoping for an answer so much, but that delay nearly killed me.
Anyway, the reason for using getRange() with no parameter is that I'm making an add-in for my school, which is supposed to make personal schedule for all teachers out of the large, full schedule that contains the details about all the teachers, students, etc. So, As I don't really know what's the height of that document in the code, I needed to scan the whole document (in fact, just the used ranges, but what about the blank ones? For this reason, insert "" to the cell's personal schedule).

Comment: I'll try my best to use getUsedRanges() instead. As I said, thank you so much! You saved me LoL

Comment: If there is a completely blank worksheet, `getUsedRange()` *queried off of the `Worksheet` object* will return just the "A1" cell.  This is done for parity with VBA, which also returned "A1" instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do `getUsedRange()` off of a **Range** object, that one *will* throw an exception if the entire Range is empty (VBA doesn't have such method, so we felt like we had more creative license there).  Though if you want a non-throwing version, there is also a `range.getUsedRangeOrNullObject()`.  Null objects are strange beasts, but you can read about them in detail in my book (it's a cool pattern, but it just takes a bit of getting used to)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually solved it - simply iterating over the values multidimensional array won't throw an exception, would it?

Comment: Correct, an empty sheet will just have a used range of A1, and hence its values will be [[""]].  So assuming your code handles a single-cell entry correctly, you'll be fine (I.e., the exception, if any, would come from your code, not from the framework)

Comment: Of course. I console logged the result and it went fine. But, now a different annoying problem has raised - is there a function like insertToSheetFromBeginning(multidimensionalArray) to simplify the insertion, or do I have to use the getRange(maximum possible addresses) ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understood the question.  But maybe ask it in a different thread (and that way, you can give more details or a drawing, too).  Feel free to post the link here once you do

Comment: I have a 2-dimensional array of values. As of now, the only way I know for inserting values into a sheet is by `newSheetRange.getRange(cellTopLeftAddress + ":" + cellBottomRightAddress).values = valuesToInsert`. But, is there a simpler way, especially when simply inserting the values to a new, blank sheet?

Comment: Yes, there is a simpler way without knowing the addresses.  But please ask it as a separate question, so others can learn as well (otherwise it will just get lost in the comments...)